# Differential equation maximum height

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Came across this A level question...

As a tree grows, the rate of increase of its height, $h$ m, with respect to time, $t$ years after planting, is modelled by the differential equation

$\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{1}{10}\sqrt{16-\frac{1}{2}h}$

The tree is planted as a seedling of negligible height, so that $h=0$ when $t=0$.

(i) state the maximum height of the tree, according to this model

I thought of solving $\frac{dh}{dt}=0$ and get $h=32$ which is the maximum height possible.

However, $h=32$ actually occurs at the end point and the derivative does not exist there. What if I say the height is strictly increasing as $\frac{dh}{dt}>0$ for all $0\leq h\leq32$ and therefore the maximum height is 32m.

Any view on this? Would appreciate if you can offer your opinion on how to answer this question and justify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to make a direct equation relating $h$ and $t$ instead for this problem. Solving $\frac {dh}{dt}=0$ gave you the correct height (luckily) but that is not the right way to do it. 
$$\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{1}{10}\sqrt{16-\frac{1}{2}h}$$
$$\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{\sqrt{32-h}}{10\sqrt 2}$$
$$\int\frac{dh}{\sqrt{32-h}}=\int\frac{dt}{10\sqrt 2}$$
$$-2\sqrt{32-h}=\frac{t^2}{10\sqrt 2}$$
$$4(32-h)=\frac {t^2}{200}$$
$$h=32-\frac {t^2}{800}$$
From here, we can conclude that the maximum height is $32$. Also, derivative being zero does not mean that it does not exist. $32$ is a perfectly valid answer but anything greater and the derivative and time become undefined.